# Images not being displayed in grid view

Tags: android, gridview, activeandroid

I am trying to populate a grid view with images stored in the database using Active Android. The database is being populated when a post is added, however, the images are not being shown inside the grid view.

I don't think that there is any problem with the grid view since when debugging, I am showing layout boundaries and the grid view items are shown (without images).

This is my code.

Post Class

```
@Table(name = "Posts")
public class Post extends Model {
    @Column(name = "Title")
    public String title;
    @Column(name = "Content")
    public String description;
    @Column(name = "Section")
    public String section;
    @Column(name = "Image")
    public Bitmap image;

    public Post() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Image Adapter Class

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Post> posts;
    public ImageAdapter(Context c, List<Post> posts)
    {
        mContext = c;
        this.posts=posts;
    }

    //returns number of items in ArrayList
    public int getCount() {
        return posts.size();
    }

    //returns a reference to the current image
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    //creating a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageBitmap(posts.get(position).image);
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Fragment Class - code for the grid view is inside the onCreateView method

```
public class Fragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";
    private int mPage;
    List<Post> toShow;

    //the inflation logic is defined for the fragment tab content
    public static Fragment newInstance(int page) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        Fragment fragment = new Fragment ();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Science", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public static List<Post> getAll() {
        return new Select()
                .from(Post.class)
                .execute();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment, container, false);
        toShow=getAll();
        GridView gridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getContext(),toShow));
        return view;
    }
}
```

And this is the method in which I am populating the database

```
 public void submitAction(View view)
    {
        /*This method creates a new post and populates it with the data added by the user. The data is then stored in the database
        * using the Active Android Library.*/
        Post p = new Post();
        EditText title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.post_title_input);
        String tit = title.getText().toString();
        EditText description = (EditText)findViewById((R.id.editText));
        String desc = description.getText().toString();
        Bitmap img = yourSelectedImage;
        p.title=tit;
        p.description=desc;
        p.section="science";
        p.image=img;

        if(tit.matches("")) //not recognised
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Title should not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else if(desc.matches("")) //not recognised
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Description should not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else if(img==null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image should be selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else
        {
            p.save();// storing entry in database
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(this, News.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
```

Would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Check your `Bitmap` Should be null.  Try Debug.

Comment: When it is saved in the database it is not Null. However, I am trying to place a break point in the Fragment where toShow=getAll(); however, it is not breaking there. But since the gridView is being populated according to the number of posts saved, I don't think that the image is null

Comment: I managed to debug it. In fact, yes. The image is null. Do you know what might be the problem? When it is saved, it is not being saved as null

Comment: Check this for suggestion how to do not store images in DB https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/issues/105

Comment: Don't store bitmap in database, try storing image path in database, use glide or picasso library to download images as these libraries provide offline images capability as well